# How to customize unity-greeter

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, unity-greeter

The only thing I don't like about the default greeter is that the input box with user list etc. is aligned to the left. I want to have it centered. The only ways to customize unity-greeter I found only changed font, logo and background.

I don't see .ui file and people say that this greeter is 'hardcoded'. So, I've downloaded sources from launchpad, but what I found was only a bunch of vala files, no markup or anything related to positioning/aligning, but adding some classes some to elements. No idea how it all works.

What I want is to customize it to look something like

[image: this]

I just need to center those ui elements. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apt-get source unity-greeter` to get the source files.
The lines you are looking for are in `/usr/sbin/greeter-list.vala`, especially around ~line 100 might be interesting to you.

Compilation is possible with `sudo debuild -i -us -uc`